# ThreeJS Ray has intersections with invisible planes?

Tags: opengl-es, 3d, webgl, three.js

I've been studying ThreeJS and I can't figure out the current issue.

When I cast a ray from my camera it has too many intersections, and some of those are not even near of my actual plane. I should be finding the intersection, which is actually piercing my visible plane. Any ideas how to do that?

Example (Double click the plane, Each box represents the intersection. Should work with Chrome and FF):
http://concurio.com/webgl/threejs-plane.html

Comment: Have you tried with latest version of Threejs?

Comment: One thing that's buggy in the code is that the canvas is not aligned to top-left corner of the page, so the mouse coords are a bit offset. Testing the code with an unmodified plane geometry, everything works as it should. If I add offsets to the vertex z-coordinates the returned intersection points are wrong (for an interesting visualization, do the intersection test & vis in mousemove handler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call computeCentroids and computeFaceNormals on your geometry. And even then, the intersection code only works on planar faces. If you need to have non-planar quads in your geometry, you need to use triangles instead. Or fix the bug in Three.js (filed issue at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1357 )

Also, move the renderer.domElement to the top-left of the page.

In short, try this:

```
var s = renderer.domElement.style;
s.left = s.top = '0px';
s.position = 'absolute';

var planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(400, 200, 40, 40);
for ( var i = 0, l = planeGeo.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
  // planar quad faces 
  var p = planeGeo.vertices[i].position;
  p.z = Math.sin(p.y / 20)*40;
}
planeGeo.computeFaceNormals();
planeGeo.computeCentroids();
```

[update] In the dev branch of Three.js, there's THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads which you can use as a workaround. It already computes face normals and centroids, so you only need to add this one line to your code:

```
THREE.GeometryUtils.triangulateQuads(planeGeo);
```